# Unlocking mutex won't return `MutexGuard`

Tags: rust

On the code below:

```
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex, MutexGuard};
use std::sync::{LockResult, PoisonError};

pub struct MutexGuardOptionRef<'a, T: ?Sized> {
    pub mutex_guard: MutexGuard<'a, Option<Box<T>>>,
}

pub trait LockableOption<T: ?Sized> {
    fn lock(&self) -> LockResult<MutexGuardOptionRef<T>>;
}

pub type LockableArc<T> = Arc<Mutex<Option<T>>>;

impl<T> LockableOption<T> for LockableArc<Box<T>> {
    fn lock(&self) -> LockResult<MutexGuardOptionRef<T>> {
        let mutex_guard = self.lock();
        match mutex_guard {
            Ok(m) => Ok(MutexGuardOptionRef{
                mutex_guard: m
            }),
            _ => unimplemented!()
        }
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=1e24cdcf5a8886eb4c3dfcd0eb02a9ef)

we have

```
impl<T> LockableOption<T> for LockableArc<Box<T>> {
    fn lock(&self) -> LockResult<MutexGuardOptionRef<T>> {
```

since we're implementing for `LockableArc<Box<T>>`, then `self: LockableArc<Box<T>>`, so calling `self.lock()` would call `LobkcableArc::lock` which is `Mutex::lock` which should give `MutexGuard`, but it's saying it gives `MutexGuardOptionRef`:

Error:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/lib.rs:19:30
   |
19 |                 mutex_guard: m
   |                              ^ expected struct `MutexGuard`, found struct `MutexGuardOptionRef`
   |
   = note: expected struct `MutexGuard<'_, Option<Box<T>>>`
              found struct `MutexGuardOptionRef<'_, T>`
```

What is happening?

Comment: @PeterHall sorry, what should come after `mutex_guard`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you're seeing this problem is because your `self.lock` call is actually recursive.  That is `self.lock()` calls `LockableArc<Box<T>::lock`, not the `lock` method on `Mutex`.  As a result, the type of `m` is `MutexGuardOptionRef`, not `MutexGuard<'a, Option<Box<T>>`.  The compiler will warn you that this call is unconditionally recursive if you change `mutex_guard: m` to `mutex_guard: m.mutex_guard`.

Obviously, that change will fix the compilation error, but since it will always recurse, you won't want to actually do that.  Instead, you probably need to specify the method you want to call more precisely, as `Mutex::lock(self)`, like so:

```rust
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex, MutexGuard};
use std::sync::LockResult;

pub struct MutexGuardOptionRef<'a, T: ?Sized> {
    pub mutex_guard: MutexGuard<'a, Option<Box<T>>>,
}

pub trait LockableOption<T: ?Sized> {
    fn lock(&self) -> LockResult<MutexGuardOptionRef<T>>;
}

pub type LockableArc<T> = Arc<Mutex<Option<T>>>;

impl<T> LockableOption<T> for LockableArc<Box<T>> {
    fn lock(&self) -> LockResult<MutexGuardOptionRef<T>> {
        let mutex_guard = Mutex::lock(self);
        match mutex_guard {
            Ok(m) => Ok(MutexGuardOptionRef{
                mutex_guard: m
            }),
            _ => unimplemented!()
        }
    }
}
```

That both fixes the unconditional recursion, and gives you the result of the type you were expecting.